# Error with declaring map of vector

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, stl

I am trying to declare of map of vector but it's giving an error.

My code:

```
int main() {

    map <int, vector<int> > ele;

return 0;
}
```

**Error :**

```
In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >*, unsigned int)':
q2.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt13_Rb_tree_nodeISt4pairIKiSt6vectorIiSaIiEEEEE10deallocateEPS8_j[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >*, unsigned int)]+0xd): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/ccjbk0JX.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned int)':
q2.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPij[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned int)]+0xd): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/ccjbk0JX.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
/tmp/ccjbk0JX.o:(.eh_frame+0xa7): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I cannot understand this error.
Please help.

Comment: What command are you using to compile? also can you show the includes of the program.

Comment: There is no error in this code: http://ideone.com/vQgu7n Use g++ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error usually arises when you try and compile C++ code with gcc, try using g++.
If that still fails try passing -lstdc++ (eg. g++ main.c -lstdc++ ).